# How do I factorize this exact differential?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I know for a fact that $$(x+y)dx + (x-y)dy$$ is an exact differential since their partial derivatives are the same (both equates to 1). How do I find that $df$ that could capture this entire equation? I can't see how since there is a $-1$ to the $y$. My closest guess is $\frac{1}{2}(x+y)^2$ but I cannot get the negative $y$.

Comment: An "exact differential" means that it is $(\partial f/\partial x)dx+(\partial f/\partial y)dy$.  Write down equations for your case and solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't guess! There are algorithms for doing this. Integrate $\partial f/\partial x = x+y$ with respect to $x$ to get $f(x,y) = \frac12 x^2 + xy + g(y)$, where $g$ is the "constant of integration." Now compare $\partial f/\partial y$ and figure out $g(y)$, similarly. (By the way, there are numerous posts showing how to do this on this site. I know I've posted several answers myself.)

Comment: Thanks Ted. I've got to the point where by comparing $g(y)$, I am able to get $g(y) = -y$ but this gives me $f = x^2/2 + xy - y$, which is not the correct answer. Guessing further seems to give me $f = x^2/2 + xy - y^2/2$ which seems correct. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I just found my mistake in the integration. I should've gotten dg/dy and not just g(y) directly.